# AutoMapper: Ignore source parameter when mapping to destination class

Tags: automapper

I want to use AutoMapper to map classes but also to prevent a source parameter from mapping over.

```
public class Dest
{
    public string strInclude { get; set; }
}
 
public class Source
{
    public string strInclude { get; set; }
    public string strIgnore { get; set; }
}

Mapper.CreateMap<Dest, Source>()
    //code to prevent strIgnore from mapping over to Dest
```

I can find plenty of examples for ignoring destination parameters ie

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Dest, Source>()
    .ForMember(dest => dest.strIgnore, src => src.Ignore());
```

However, I can't seem to find the reverse case.

Comment: In your example, `Source` *is* the destination type, so `Source.strIgnore` will be ignored in the mapping.